# CSS in Magento is applying site-wide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I'm pretty new to magento, but basically I have a small (I hope) issue. I made an entire new landing page, based on bootstrap and using plenty of JS and my own CSS styles.

I then tried to create a new category with it via Catalog > Categories and just define the HTML of that page right there in the page description, changing the resources links to an internal folder somewhere else on the website.

The problem: it applies site wide when used with 1-column or 2 column pages. This: http://www.nameon.se/gavor/gift-advice-test is the problem.

It works only if used with an empty page, like this: http://www.nameon.se/gavor/gift-advice-1 but that's not what I want.

How can I add an internal 1-column or 2-column category or self-standing page that has the menu and footer of magento and everything, but being self-contained, without applying the style or anything site-wide?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and do things the 'Magento way' and keep your custom page within the CMS rather than as a standalone html page. The answer is to create a new page layout by adding a (very small) module using this tutorial;

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/

And then adding your page specific CSS and JS files to that page only using the design layout update XML like below;

[image: Magento layout override xml for JS on specific page]

You can also add CSS, like the example below

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem">
          <type>skin_js</type>
          <name>js/locationmap.js</name>
     </action>  
     <action method="addCss">
          <stylesheet>css/your.css</stylesheet>
     </action>
</reference>
```